# Laravel 4.1 first route add, gives error.

Tags: nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I just installed laravel 4.1 using the recommended install option.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

All went fine, as I was able to see the default page inside `/public/` then I removed the `.htaccess` file since I am using nginx and added `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` for nginx inside the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` then I created a simple route

```
Route::get('/about', function()
{
    return "about page";
});
```

but I am getting the common `404 Not Found nginx/1.0.15` from nginx. I have given 777 permission even to the entire laravel folder. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds more like a nginx problem than a laravel problem. Are you able to get the default homepage to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point your nginx to the public folder. Here's one of my site config files in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

This way, you can browse to your laravel project by requesting: `http://localhost/`
Watch out: maybe you php cgi is different: use the `fastcgi_pass` rule you already had.
And readding the `.htaccess` file doesn't do any harm.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I have created two `location /{ ... }` and I guess they conflicted.

Comment: Feel free to check out my new question on changing `127.0.0.1:8080` to just `localhost` :)